# What does picking up Winter Gifts in TF2 do?

Tags: team-fortress-2

In the new TF2 winter update I have noticed that when some people die, they leave behind a gift. I have picked several of these gifts up, but nothing has been placed in my inventory and I have gotten no notifications except an achievement for picking up 3 of the gifts. Do these gifts have any other purpose?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an [achievement](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Christmas_Event_achievements) for picking up 3 of them.  Beyond that, [they do nothing at all](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Pickups#Event_pickups)

### Valve Gift Grab 2011 – TF2

Collect three gifts dropped by opponents.

Comment: I'd be willing to bet that at some point during this winter sale, getting this achievement will earn you a "present."

Comment: As of December 28, the achievement now completes an "objective" and earns a present.